# How to ignore accent using breeze local query?

Tags: javascript, breeze, diacritics, non-ascii-characters, accent-insensitive

I am using breeze to query data from local, but I have some problems to remove diacritics and query with accent insensitive. For example:

```
var name = 'HELEN';
var pred = new breeze.Predicate('name', breeze.FilterQueryOp.Contains, name);
```

Results:
HELEN, HELENA, HELENE

But I need all results:
HELEN, HELENA, HÉLÈNA, HELENE, HÉLÈNE

It's possible the next:

```
var name = 'HELEN';
var pred = new breeze.Predicate('removeDiacritics(name)', breeze.FilterQueryOp.Contains, removeDiacritics(name));
```

Thanks. Any help will be greatly appreciated.